# Google displays different cache/summary for same URL

Tags: google-cache

Google is displaying two different cache versions of the same URL based on the query used to find it. I've tried resubmitting the page for indexing, but since one cached version is older than the other, maybe it thinks it has the latest version.

If you Google "the emerald magazine" https://www.google.com/search?q=the+emerald+magazine

You get the correct cache.

If you Google "emerald magazine" https://www.google.com/search?q=emerald+magazine

...in the summary you get a vulgar reference to copulation. (at least until it is fixed)

Everything I can see indicates these are the same URL with different caches. It has been this way for days. A non-google web tool tells me it was scanned three days ago.

I've submitted the page for re-indexing. What is the next step toward getting this resolved? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *I've submitted the page for re-indexing.*, however, am I to assume that you used Fetch as Google in Google Webmaster Tools?? If so, click fetch and index. I did not pull up the second cache- but your WordPress may have been hacked. Make sure it is up to date including all themes and plug-ins. As well, run an anti-virus scan on the entire set of hard-drives including rootkit to make sure there isn't a virus. There are viruses that operate outside of WP installs and keep hacking the site even after updates and corrections. If it is not a WP site, let us know.

Comment: Do you really mean the [cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ftheemeraldmagazine.com%2F), or do you only refer to the snippet/summary shown on the SERP?

Comment: I meant the snippet. I used fetch as google/index. I should have been more specific. Thanks for the info! I'm still investigating if it was hacked vs. virus etc. but it makes a lot more sense what's happening now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a problem.

Your second link points to your website and google picks up the vulgar text as part of its description. When I looked at the HTML source code, I managed to find the exact same vulgar text in the code itself.

This suggests to me that someone has hacked at least one webpage on your website. You should remove the advertisements right away until you get the text in your page(s) fixed.

Next, make stronger passwords for all your accounts associated with web publishing, which may include FTP and wordpress (or other content management system) administration accounts, etc.

Once you make the immediate changes, double check the HTML and run it through the w3c validator and google's page-speed insights. Make sure your description is nice and accurate. The ideal objective is to have only your title and description displayed in the search results.

Once you have done all that, use the fetch as google tool in webmaster tools to make sure it sees the page the way it is supposed to be displayed then select the submit to index button when the fetch works.

Comment: Good point about changing the passwords!! I forgot that. WP is hacked all the time. We get tons of questions here like this one. WP users must use up to date WP code and check to make sure that plug-ins and **themes** are secure and up to date. As well, it is important to know that there are viruses out there that work outside of WP and will re-hack the site over and over again until the virus is removed. I cannot emphasize enough to make sure the site is secure first or no fix will hold. WP users must be vigilant more than most!!

Comment: About one fourth of the whole internet runs with WordPress. Saying that itv"get hacked all the time" implies that it is not secure, while it only means that it is the biggest target to attack. Once that is made clear, please change the administrator account from "admin" to ANYTHING else.

Comment: That explains why theres a 75% chance at best I'll be able to work in my field for a company. because too many companies rely on CMS's especially wordpress and I bet not one single soul in any company thinks about the security of their setup. Heck, people even try to hack my server (that I get to manage for my side job) all the time and they never get anywhere. Man if there was only a company that would pay big bucks for website security promotion, I'd be rich.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Here's what threw me; the vulgarity only shows up if you *aren't logged in* to WordPress. My bad for not widening my search. However, the first thing that threw me was Google showing different summaries for different queries resulting in the same URL. I wasn't seeing in the source of that page so I thought Google had the page wrong.